# ASP.NET MVC: Guardar en variable int un ID desde una consulta select en sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo un codigo para un login, donde guardo el username del usuario que se logueo en `Session["USERNAME"]`. Lo que pretendo es meter en mi variable `wea` el ID del usuario que se acaba de logear utilizando su username en una consulta sql. Como es logico no he obtenido resultado alguno y por eso acudo aca para ver si alguien me puede decir cual seria la forma correcta de hacer lo que quiero hacer. Gracias por sus respuestas.

```
 public ActionResult Login(EMPLEADOS empleado)
    {
            using (ConnectionContext db = new ConnectionContext())
            {
                var usr = db.EMPLEADOS.Where(u => u.USERNAME == empleado.USERNAME && u.PASSWORD == empleado.PASSWORD).FirstOrDefault();
                if (usr != null)
                {
                int wea = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM dbo.EMPLEADOS WHERE USERNAME = @empleado.USERNAME");
                    Session["ID"] = wea.ToString();
                    Session["USERNAME"] = empleado.USERNAME.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("Logeado");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuario o Contraseña invalido");
                }
            }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En la variable **usr** ya tienes el usuario logueado. Si es diferente de null es por que encontró en base de datos.

Espero te sirva

```
    public ActionResult Login(EMPLEADOS empleado)
    {
       using (ConnectionContext db = new ConnectionContext())
       {
          var usr = db.EMPLEADOS.Where(u => u.USERNAME == empleado.USERNAME && u.PASSWORD == empleado.PASSWORD).FirstOrDefault();
          if (usr != null)
          { 
             // Se encontró el usuario en base de datos
             int wea = usr.Id;
             Session["ID"] = usr.Id.ToString();
             Session["USERNAME"] = usr.USERNAME.ToString();
             return RedirectToAction("Logeado");
          }
          else
          {
              ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuario o Contraseña invalido");
          }
       }
        return View();
    }
```